# Size issues (small/large categories) when defining stacks in the Algebraic/differentiable/topological setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory

Angelo Vistoli in the notes [Notes on Grothendieck topologies, fibered categories and descent theory](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf) starts the section of category theory with the following note:

> We will not distinguish between small and large categories. More
>   generally, we will ignore any set-theoretic difficulties. These can be
>   overcome with standard arguments using universes.

Question : Which of the notions introduced in Angelo Vistoli's notes assumes that the category is small? In particular their application to Algebraic/differentiable/topological stacks?

For example, Behrang Noohi puts the following extra condition in his [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503247.pdf) on topological stacks:

> Throughout the paper, all topological spaces are assumed to be compactly generated.

This could be because, the category $\text{Top}$ of all topological spaces is **not a small category**.

Are there any places one has to be careful to not allow large categories?

Some references to support this question :

1. nlab [says](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/site) "In technical terms, a site is a **small** category equipped with a coverage or Grothendieck topology". It also says (Remark $2.3$ at same page)  "Often a site is required to be a small category. But also large sites play a role."
2. David Metzler in [Topological and Smooth Stacks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306176.pdf) defines (page $2$) a site as a small category equipped with Grothendieck topology. It further says "We will want to discuss, for example, “the category of stacks on the category of all topological spaces,” but strictly speaking this does not exist, since the category of topological spaces does not have a set of objects, but rather a proper class. To avoid this problem we will consider throughout some fixed category $\mathbb{T}$ of topological spaces which has a set of objects, or at least, is equivalent to such a category".

So, it "looks like", even though one can define a site over a large category, and then a stack over a site (which was defined on a large category), one often restricts (for computational purposes or personal interests) to a small categories and stacks on them. Is this what it is or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I am not asking how does one modify definitions of Angelo Vistoli's notes so that there is no issue when dealing with large categories...

Comment: If I am not confusing something, "using universes" in this context just means the following: if you encounter a functor that should be representable but is not, you enlarge your category by adjoining a representing object for your functor. From this point of view, whether you distinguish small/large or not, there still remains a distinction: a functor is either representable or not.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Hi, thanks for the response. I am not aware of what you have mentioned. I would like to read more if you can point me to some reference regarding making something a  representable functor by adding an object representing it.. Idea is clear but some more details might clear somethings for me...

Comment: Well when you use subcanonical Grothendieck topologies, you basically do just that - make some non-representable functors representable. So any text on topos theory might be viewed relevant for that. I will come back if I figure out something more to the point.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე sue, thank you :)

Comment: I don't think assuming that topological space are compactly generated has anything to do with a size problem. The category of compactly generated topological space is not small either. It probably has to do with wanting to consider exponential of topological space (maping space).

Comment: @SimonHenry oh. Sorry. I did not think if the category of compactly generated topological spaces is small or not.. I have done a rough reading of the paper by Behrang Noohi, could not find where exactly they use this restriction.. I will do another reading and see if they have done something similar to what you have mentioned. Thanks for the tip..

Comment: I wonder why there is no tag for “topological stacks”..

Comment: I was misled by such statements early in my career - universes do *not* allow you to ignore the difference between small and large categories. Rather, universes allow us to replace the distinction between set and proper class with the distinction between a set belonging to a fixed universe $\mathcal{U}$ and a set (still not a class) outside that universe. This means we can still apply all set-theoretic operations to "large" sets, because we never use proper classes. The definition of complete and cocomplete category must be adapted to use diagrams from $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: @RobertFurber I don’t have much experience with universes.. It would be useful if you can make your comment as an answer with some more details.

Comment: can you make your comment as an answer adding some details which you think might be relevant. @SimonHenry Reading some places revealed that this condition on Topological spaces has something to do with Cartesian closedness

Comment: Yes. The category of topological space is not cartesian closed but the category of compactly generated is. This has nothing to do with size problem, but with properties of the compact-open topology. I'm affraid I don't really have more details to add to my comment, I think David Robert's answer pretty much cover everything.

Comment: @SimonHenry Ok. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there any places one has to be careful to not allow large categories?

No. For the purposes of forming the 2-category of algebraic/topological/differentiable stacks, or more generally, some kind of presentable stacks over a large category there are no size issues. Naively, the 2-category of stacks on $S$ is carved out from the presheaf category $[S^{op},\mathbf{Cat}]$ (or $[S^{op},\mathbf{Gpd}]$), which *does* present size issues for $S$ not essentially small. However, the 2-category of presentable stacks (of groupoids, say, which is the case you are looking at) is equivalent to the [bicategory of internal groupoids and anafunctors](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html) (and transformations). This can be [defined elementarily](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04552) from the 2-category of internal groupoids, *functors* and natural transformations. Given a [quite weak size condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/WISC#in_other_sites__external_version) on the site structure—that is, the size of generating sets of covering families—this bicategory is even locally essentially small. The only case 'in the wild' that I know of that fails this weak condition is the [fpqc topology](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022A) on categories of schemes, and algebraic geometers are a bit wary of that: see [tag 0BBK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BBK). They are happy to say a single presheaf (of sets, modules, groupoids) is a stack for the fpqc topology, but generally talk about sheaves/stacks for the [fppf topology](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021L) at the finest: see the definition in [tag 026O](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026O).

**Added** For a large site not satisfying the condition [WISC](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/WISC), the sheafification or stackification functors might not exist. This problem, however, does not impact considering presentable stacks, only when one is wanting to think about arbitrary stacks. For an example of how bad this can get, Waterhouse's paper

> *Basically bounded functors and flat sheaves*, Pacific Journal of Mathematics **57** (1975), no. 2, 597–610 ([Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102906018))

gives an example of a presheaf on the fpqc site that does not admit *any* sheafification. The following quote from the Stacks Project is relevant:

> The fpqc topology cannot be treated in the same way as the fppf topology. Namely, suppose that R is a nonzero ring. We will see in Lemma 34.9.14 that there does not exist a set $A$ of fpqc-coverings of $Spec(R)$ such that every fpqc-covering can be refined by an element of $A$. If $R=k$ is a field, then the reason for this unboundedness is that there does not exist a field extension of $k$ such that every field extension of $k$ is contained in it.
>
> If you ignore set theoretic difficulties, then you run into presheaves which do not have a sheafification, see [Theorem 5.5, Waterhouse-fpqc-sheafification]. A mildly interesting option is to consider only those faithfully flat ring extensions $R\to R'$ where the cardinality of $R'$ is suitably bounded. (And if you consider all schemes in a fixed universe as in SGA4 then you are bounding the cardinality by a strongly inaccessible cardinal.) However, it is not so clear what happens if you change the cardinal to a bigger one. ([Tag 022A](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022A))

Comment: I should add that differentiable stacks can be defined using a site with countably many objects, namely the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$, so all this discussion is not needed for that case.

Comment: A side question.. David Metzler in his paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306176 assumes a site to be defined over a small category.. nlab says similar thing "Remark 2.3. Often a site is required to be a small category. But also large sites play a role" at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/site.. It looks like even defining Grothendieck topology on a large category seems to be avoided by some people.. Any specific reason for that typo of choice?

Comment: What I have understood as of now is that, even if the base category $\mathcal{S}$ is a large category, there are no size issues if I restrict my attention to the $2$-category of representable stacks over $\mathcal{S}$.. It is because this $2$-category of representable stacks over $\mathcal{S}$ is "equivalent" to the "bicategory of internal groupoids and anafunctors"..

Comment: I'm not sure what your first question is asking ("typo"?). Defining the structure of a site on a large category has no real issues, the problem is that there might not be a sheafification/stackification functor (a real size issue), even though general individual sheaves/stacks make sense. For your second question, I don't mean the 2-category of **representable** stacks, since they turn out to be sheaves of sets, but the 2-category of **presentable** stacks—this is a general term for algebraic/topological/differentiable/etc stacks over a general site. We don't need stackification for this.

Comment: I mean to say "Any specific reason for that type of choice?" For your second explanation, I think I understand what you mean.. There may not exists sheafification functor $\text{Presheaves}/\mathcal{S}\rightarrow \text{Sheaves}/\mathcal{S}$ when $\mathcal{S}$ is a large category.. I would like to read more about the precise difficulty in sheafification if you can point me to some reference..  I request you to add those lines in your previous comment to your answer.. nlab page definitio of sheafifcation starts with "Let $(C,J)$ be a site in the sense of: small category equipped with a coverage"

Comment: Waterhouse's paper _Basically bounded functors and flat sheaves_ in Pacific J. Math. (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102906018) gives an example of a presheaf on the fpqc site that does not admit a sheafification.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.. it is a short paper,I think I will be able to learn something from it..

Comment: added link for WISC. Your answer also had a link but it was not "clickable". I do not know why it is like that...

Comment: OK, thanks. Must have been a markdown formatting mistake on my part.